# Juniper / SRX-100 / Repurpose old device / Disable DHCP?

Tags: juniper, dhcp, juniper-srx

I have an old Juniper SRX-100.  I want to re-purpose it for my network.  I need to extend the network in a new location, so I need more ports.  I could use a simple switch, but I have this laying around.

1. The Firmware is *really* old.  Should I upgrade to the latest release (12.3X48-D found at https://support.juniper.net/support/downloads/?f=srx)
2. I cannot figure out how to use the J-Web to disable DHCP.  I have a router at the **head** of my network.  I don't really need more routers handing out addresses.

- How do I configure so it does not hand out addresses on *any* of the ports?
- Do I need to configure a port specifically to be the relay up to the router that is providing DHCP?

Comment: If you need a switch, then buy a switch. Attempting to use this as a dumb switch is just going to be a headache.

Comment: Thanks Ricky.  Wanted an outside opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use obsolete or ill-suited devices. Just buy a switch.

Comment: Understood.  Just needed an outside opinion.  Seemed like a *square peg* in a *round hole* at first.